# SimpleOnGestureListener, onDoubleTapEvent suspends after short while until gesture is finished

Tags: android

I'm trying to use a double-tap and hold/move to implement a panning action (single-tap and hold/move is already taken by the rotation action). However, the onDoubleTapEvent function receives only about 18 MotionEvents while the user moves, then suspends until the user finishes the gestures, at which point it will receive one more MotionEvent before actually finishing the gesture.

So the user can pan the object a short distance, at which point it will freeze, even though the user is still dragging. When the user releases, the object will snap to the right position. I'd hoped the user would be able to drag/pan as long as she/he wants to. Any tips would really be appreciated.

This is the implementation of the onDoubleTap and onDoubleTapEvent functions:

```
            @Override
            public boolean onDoubleTap(MotionEvent event) {

                eventpan.x = event.getX();
                eventpan.y = event.getY();

                return true;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onDoubleTapEvent(MotionEvent event) {

                oglrenderer.panx +=   0.005f * ( event.getX() - eventpan.x);
                oglrenderer.pany += - 0.005f * ( event.getY() - eventpan.y);

                eventpan.x = event.getX();
                eventpan.y = event.getY();

                return true;
            }
```

This just changes the x and y coordinates for translation in the renderer, who's onDraw function basically looks like this:

```
public void onDrawFrame(GL10 gl) {          

    gl.glClear(GL10.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL10.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    gl.glLoadIdentity();                        
    gl.glPushMatrix();                 

    gl.glTranslatef(panx, pany, zoom); 

    object.draw(gl);               

    gl.glPopMatrix();  
    gl.glFlush();


}
```

I'm currently designing for Android 4.0, API level 14. Again, any tips would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Not so much an answer as a tip. I'm trying to solve a similar issue, and I found that a LongPress event occurs, which puts an end to most future events. Look into it; it seems that the GestureDetector class forces a return true on LongClick events, or something like that. I'll continue looking at it, and hopefully come up with a proper solution soon.

EDIT: So for the moment I went setIsLongpressEnabled(false) to allow the double-tap-scroll to work. Not so great, as I do want a LongClick gesture as well eventually, but it's working for now.